# Can you reproduce prompthero results using just the given prompt and parameters?

Tags: stable-diffusion

For example, starting from https://prompthero.com/prompt/d57c644358f

[image]

Prompt:

```
"Girl with a pearl earring" modern digital photograph, in italy, sitting at an outdoor cafe looking at her cellphone, latte sitting on the table

Negative prompt: bad-picture-chill-75v-2101

resolution 2048x3072  seed 122182646 guidance scale 7 steps 200 sampler dpm++_2_ancestral MODEL USED Stable Diffusion 1.5
```

Here is what I get with:

```
"Girl with a pearl earring" modern digital photograph, in italy, sitting at an outdoor cafe looking at her cellphone, latte sitting on the table
Seed: 122182646, Dimensions: 768x1280, Sampler: dpmpp_2s_a, Inference Steps: 200, Guidance Scale: 7.5, Model: sd-v1-5, Negative Prompt: bad-picture-chill-75v-2101
```

[image]